# Git-tfs Clone: Option to not create temporary workspace (or specify existing permanent workspace)?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, git-tfs

How might I run git tfs clone without permissions to create a temporary workspace--or, alternatively, specify an existing permanent workspace which git tfs should not cleanup afterward?

Running command:

```
git tfs clone --branches=all http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultTFSCollection "$/Project"
```

Error:

```
TF14044: User {USER} needs the CreateWorkspace global permission(s).
```

For what it's worth, our TFS admins create workspaces (same as %COMPUTERNAME%). However, my user does not have permissions to create workspaces.

Have downloaded and identified the source code location which seems to perform the temporary workspace creation.

However, can I just not do so? What benefit does a temporary workspace provide?

Use case: Migrating away from TFS 2012 TFVC, to Git (Azure DevOps). So just want to clone. No future need to write back to TFS TFVC.

Thank you

Comment: *our TFS admins create workspaces*. This is a *really* weird setup that I've never encountered in over a decade of working with TFVC. I doubt `git-tfs` supports it; it expects to be able to create a workspace to use.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience--asking the TFS admins for the ability to create workspaces seems to represent the consensus, so I'll make my case and see what they determine to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, git-tfs doesn't have this option to use an existing workspace because it would have been difficult to check if the existing workspace have been created from the good TFVC path.

And also, if you want to clone with branch support, you need to create multiple workspaces at different places so git-tfs need to handle them itself.

If you are in charge of the migration, your best chance is to ask your tfs administrators to grant you this right at least until you finish your migration.